# mount windows smb to ubuntu server at boot

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

mount smb with user write/read, via cifs at boot, after network.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USER,password=PASS //ADDRESS/SHARE /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/ _netdev
```

Can I add this to etc/fstab? Where do I add it (at the end?) I have a dozen similar subdirectories that need to be mounted at boot, after network on. Given they are to be accessed by various docker containers, intermittently, I am fine with them remaining mounted ongoing without an off/on like `x-systemd.automount`, however I am not sure about the benefits of unmounting/mounting on the fly based on usage. I would like it to be accessible and fast by the respective container, so I am worried a timebased unmount would add delays.

Comment: this looks good, thank you